# Getting heart rate from simple video: code inside

Tags: ios, matlab, camera, signal-processing, video-processing

I am trying to find a heart rate from a video of my skin. In order to do so, I am taking a cropped rectangle of pixels from my video frame and averaging the red (or green) component in all those pixels (then, of course, seeing how this average changes frame-to-frame).

I take a fast fourier transform of the vector (the average color value of each frame's cropped section) to see what frequencies are most prominent. I am hoping to see the resting human heart rate, ~1Hz, as very prominent.

As a test, I took a video of just a wall, or other objects that should have no periodic color change. I used a tripod and three different cameras of different brands. Each of them have similar if not identical background frequency peaks particularly at 1Hz, 2Hz, 5 Hz, and 10 Hz. I have shot under natural light and fluorescent and it still occurs.

My ultimate goal is to distinguish, with this analysis, living skin from non-vascularized skin. So understanding why I am getting these frequency peaks for inanimate objects is VITAL.

Could any of you run this code on your own videos and help explain if I am simply an idiot?

Camera shooting:

Kodak Playsport

1920x1080
30fps (60i)
imports as mp4

Canon Vixia HF200
1440x1080
30fps (60i)
12mbps bitrate
imports as .mts which I reencode to mp4

Code based off of:

http://www.ignaciomellado.es/blog/Measuring-heart-rate-with-a-smartphone-camera#video

```
clear all
close all
clc

%% pick data file name to be analyzed, set directory it is found in
dataDir = './data';
vidname = ['Filename.MP4'];

%% define path to file and pull out video
inFile = fullfile(dataDir,vidname);
video = VideoReader(inFile);

%% make 1D array with length equal to number of frames (time)

brightness = zeros(1, video.NumberOfFrames);
video_framerate = round( video.FrameRate); % note some places in the code must use integer value for framerate, others we directly use the unrounded frame rate

%% set region of interest for what you want to get average brightness of
frame = read(video, 1);
imshow(frame)
rect = getrect;
close all

xmin_pt = round(rect(1));
ymin_pt = round(rect(2)); 
section_width = round(rect(3)); 
section_height = round(rect(4));

%% select component of video (red green or blue)
component_selection = 1; % pick red , green, or blue

%% make 1D array of ROI averages
 for i = 1:video.NumberOfFrames,
     frame = read(video, i);
     section_of_interest = frame(ymin_pt:ymin_pt+section_height,xmin_pt:xmin_pt+section_width,:);
     colorPlane = section_of_interest(:, :, component_selection);
     brightness(i) = sum(sum(colorPlane)) / (size(frame, 1) * size(frame, 2));
 end


%% Filter out non-physiological frequencies
BPM_L = 40;    % Heart rate lower limit [bpm]
BPM_H = 600;   % Heart rate higher limit [bpm] This is currently set high to investigate the signal

% Butterworth frequencies must be in [0, 1], where 1 corresponds to half the sampling rate
[b, a] = butter(2, [((BPM_L / 60) / video_framerate * 2), ((BPM_H / 60) / video_framerate * 2)]);
filtBrightness = filter(b, a, brightness);


%% Trim the video to exlude the time where the camera is stabilizing
FILTER_STABILIZATION_TIME = 3;    % [seconds]
filtBrightness = filtBrightness((video_framerate * FILTER_STABILIZATION_TIME + 1):size(filtBrightness, 2));

%% Do FFT on filtered/trimmed signal
fftMagnitude = abs(fft(filtBrightness));

%% Plot results

figure(1)
subplot(3,1,1)
plot([1:length(brightness)]/video.FrameRate,brightness)
xlabel('Time (seconds)')
ylabel('Color intensity')
title('original signal')

subplot(3,1,2)
plot([1:length(filtBrightness)]/video.FrameRate,filtBrightness)
xlabel('Time (seconds)')
ylabel('Color intensity')
title('after butterworth filter and trim')


freq_dimension = ((1:round(length(filtBrightness)))-1)*(video_framerate/length(filtBrightness));

subplot(3,1,3)
plot(freq_dimension,fftMagnitude)
axis([0,15,-inf,inf])
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
ylabel('|Y(f)|')
title('Fft of filtered signal')
```

Comment: Do you have flourescent lighting that flickers at ~60Hz? Or whatever the AC frequency is at your locale? Or something else like a TV or something with a refresh rate and creating reflections (even if not visible to your own eyes)?

Comment: I tried under both natural lighting (outside) and in the office where we have fluorescents. 60Hz is pretty fast. I cannot seem to understand the 1, 2, 5, and 10Hz components that seem to be popping up in all my signals. These seem to be inherent in something I am using or doing but I am not sure. Was hoping someone would have experienced this before or have a video they could run themselves.

Comment: I was thinking interference beats with something that's close to, but not exactly at a multiple of your 30fps frame rate (which may or may not be exactly 30Hz to begin with). That would show up with some prominent freqency components in the frequency domain...

Comment: I'll test natural light in a different location sometime this week, but something tells me there is more to the story. If you throw a video through the code, let me know if you see what I see. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm guessing it's an artifact of the video encoding.  Probably it's generating i-frames at 1 Hz (one every 30), and maybe P frames every 3 (10 Hz).  (I tried your code on a video from my iPhone and saw no sharp peaks).

Comment: That has to be it. Awesome, I will look into that tomorrow and post as soon as I confirm one way or another.

Comment: Camera: HTC One M8, @ 60fps, encoding @ 25fps
Spotlight white led-bulb: Peaking at 4HZ
Camera Flash: Decreasing peaks at: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

Comment: side note: you should use a psd estimator like `pwelch` instead of `fft` which is not a consistent estimator of the spectrum!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your purpose is to "find a heart rate from a video of my skin" and "...to distinguish, with this analysis, living skin from non-vascularized skin" but your approach is "take video ... crop ... average red (or green) component .. look how it changes".

I think there is a problem with the premise.  Average means the majority signal dominates.  Human vision is an (amazing) processor of visual data and usually it takes decades of hard work to get a machine to come within even a small order of what they do.  If you can't look with your eyes at 90% of folks around you and measure their heart-rate, then an averaging approach might not be the way to go.

There are an infinite number of statistics you can take to look at how a distribution changes over time, and mean is only one of them.  If you look only at the mean you may be missing the information.

How I would do this:

1. I would operate on frame-to-frame differences.
2. Most video codecs have non-uniform time-spacing.  I would get those values so that I could track changes over actual (not assumed) time.  Your current (presumably false) signals could come from the CODEC as well as from the hardware.
3. I would make a movie such that each new frame is the difference between it and the previous frame.  I would watch it 20 times and see if my (amazing) human visual processing system can see anything clearly heart-beat-related or clearly NOT.
4. For the "NOT" remove them from processing, by mask, filter or such. 
   For related, find way to make them the region of interest by
   removing everything else, truncating pixel intensity histogram, or
   other image enhancements (blur, sharpen, re-color, edge, rotate so
   largest signal is along updated pixel axes and then process..)

AFTER the human vision apparatus can get a good signal, then I would work on making math/computer get the signal with the clear knowledge that the human apparatus is superior.

If I were tracking points/features that move over time, I would look at sub-pixel metrology methods.  I did some of this a decade ago ([thesis](http://tinyurl.com/p6ezkca)) and while I think the content might be relevant, it also might be different enough to merit a first read-through before copying and running code.

Best of luck.